# The 2.1.3 Diophantine parameterization: Most elementary proof? Positive-only version?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations, parametric, sums-of-squares

The following is a well-known result.

> **Theorem:** If $t$, $u$, $v$, and $w$ are coprime integers, with $u$ odd, satisfying
>   \begin{align}
>  t^2 &= u^2 + v^2 + w^2,
> \end{align}
>   then there exist non-negative integers $a$, $b$, $c$, and $d$, with $a+b+c+d$ odd, such that
>   \begin{align}
>  t &= a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + d^2,  \\[0.2em]
>  u &= a^2 + b^2 - c^2 - d^2, \\[0.2em]
>  v &= 2(ac+bd),  \\[0.2em]
>  w &= 2(ad-bc).
> \end{align}

It’s variously attributed to Catalan, Lebesgue, *etc.*; the first proof considered “sufficient” is credited to Dickson.

I have two questions:

1. What is the most elementary proof that is still considered sufficiently rigorous? Carmichael gives one in his *Diophantine Analysis* (§10) that would have been available to Fermat… but apparently it’s not considered "sufficiently rigorous" (?).
2. Is there a version in which $a,b,c,d$ are all positive [if $t,u,v,w$ are all positive]?

Comment: I note that since $u$ is odd, it’s always possible to find $a,b,c,d$ satisfying $u=a^2+b^2-c^2-d^2$. Maybe there’s a way to leverage that directly to deduce the other three components?

Comment: Do you know if this formula gives ALL results, please?

Comment: @OldPeter: Yes, it’s been proven to give __all__ primitive results. Of course, you need to use a scalar multiple to get the non-primitive ones.